# How to enable mouse support in tmux/vim so it continues to work even after a ssh to a remote host

Tags: vim, tmux

I am on a windows machine with an `xterm` remotely displayed from my Linux server where I run many `tmux` sessions.  I have everything setup so that my mouse works in both `tmux` and `vim` on that first server (where the tmux session resides), however when I `ssh` to a second Linux server within a `tmux` session the mouse stops working in `vim`.  Does anyone have a clue to why this happens or how I can fix it?

I am using `tmux-1.5` and `vim 7.3`.  All my settings files are the same between the Linux servers since my home directory is mapped between them.

Edit:
After looking more into this it only seems that the vim split re-sizing  is affected.  I can still set the cursor position or select text with the mouse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I seemed to have solved the problem.  It appears to be the ttymouse setting in vim.  I had it set to xterm and xterm2 seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Interesting... I had to always set `ttymouse` to "xterm2" when I was using gnu screen, but when I switched to `tmux`, mouse stopped working, and I just found that switching back to "xterm" got it working again.